# Changing image variant url when a user clicks on it

Tags: shopify, shopify-template, shopify-javascript-buy-sdk

I'am facing an issue regarding the image thumbnails view, here is the sample website (smartphonewidgets.myshopify.com)

When you click on a product variant image, the browser show up the featured image instead of the variant one.

How could I resolve this please ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to select one of your variants when a variant image is clicked, Shopify has some documentation for this along with code snippets - [Select Product Variants by Clicking their Image](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/customization/products/variants/select-variants-by-clicking-images).

Depending on your theme, the code snippets may be cut/paste or you may need to dissect them a bit and adapt them for your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i already tried the documentation you gave but it doesn't work on my theme :(